# How to create tree view menu in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, menu, treeview

In my current project, I have multiple forms for 6 different types of Promotion. My current UI design is to pop up a mini form on run which allows the users to select promotion type and direct them to each form based on the selection.

Instead, I'd like to use `TreeView` control like `Windows Explorer` left pane and group them under one main root so that I'll not need to create multiple forms for each type of promotion.

Layout will be like this:

[image]

> My question is how can I manage controls from different forms?

If I put all the controls together under one form and show/hide on `NodeMouseClick` Event, my design view will be very messy.

In `tab control`, I can `manage a related set of controls under each tab`.

But I think that using tab control for each type of promotion is not the right way to do it.

Any help or suggestion will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to convert your application to [MDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you can reuse your existing forms.

Answer (score 0):

If the controls on each form are the same but with different values you can easily use one form and a list of a collection of values that you can plug the values from the appropriate collection into the form.  If the controls will be different, design different panels or groupboxes that you can store in memory and add to the form as needed.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach could be to work with user controls.

Something like this should work

```
    private UCDummy1 ucDummy1;

    private void TreeView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = new TreeViewItem();
        item.Header = "Options";
        item.ItemsSource = new string[] {"Dummy1", "Dummy2", "Dummy3"};
        var tree = sender as TreeView;
        tree.Items.Add(item);

        PopulateConfigUserControls();
    }

    private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var tree = sender as TreeView;
        if (tree.SelectedItem is string)
        {
            string selectedUC = tree.SelectedItem.ToString();

            PanelOption.Children.Clear();

            if (selectedUC == "Dummy1")
            {
                PanelOption.Children.Add(ucDummy1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PopulateConfigUserControls()
    {
        ucDummy1 = new UCDummy1();
        ucDummy1.TextBoxVoornaam.Text = Settings.Default.Voornaam;
        ucDummy1.TextBoxAchternaam.Text = Settings.Default.Achternaam;
    }

    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.Voornaam = ucDummy1.TextBoxVoornaam.Text;
        Settings.Default.Achternaam = ucDummy1.TextBoxAchternaam.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```